# Finding domain of $ f(x) ^ {g(x)} $?

Tags: functions

My coaching module says "for domain of  $ k(x)= f(x) ^ {g(x)} $ conventionally the conditions are $f(x)>0$ and $g(x)$ must be real." I get why $g(x)$ must be real, but why must $f(x)>0$ ? If for instance $f(x) = -1$,why wouldn't $k(x)$ be real? Please help me in understanding this.

Comment: What is $(-1)^\pi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $x^p$ for $x\le0$ is well defined only for some $p=\frac{m}n$ rational with $n$ odd therefore for the real functions in the form $f(x)^{g(x)}$ we require that $f(x)>0$ even if also for $f(x)\le 0$ for some value of $g(x)$ the expression can be well defined.

For example

- $(-1)^{\frac12}=N.D.$
- $(-1)^{\frac23}=1$
- $0^{\frac23}=0$
- $0^{-\frac23}=N.D.$